# In Service folder of an ASP.NET Core project, how to populate a list from a SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In a class in Service folder of an `ASP.NET CORE` project (using VS2015) you can manually populate a list as follows:

```
public interface IStateService  
{
    IEnumerable<State> List();
}

public class StateService : IStateService  
{
    public IEnumerable<State> List() {
        return new List<State>
        {
            new State { Abbreviation = "AK", Name = "Alaska" },
            new State { Abbreviation = "AL", Name = "Alabama" }
        };
    }
}
```

How the above list can be populated from a SQL server Database table, say, States with columns, say, StateName, StateCode? **NOTE**: I'm using Entity Framework Core.

Comment: are you using entity framework

Comment: @MidhunMundayadan Yes. I've just added a note on it.

Comment: do you want create a text file in that or something else

Answer (score 0):

populate list using linq and return the list where ever u want to use

```
 Context yourcontext = new Context();     

 var ddllist = yourcontext.tablename.select(c=>new{id = c.StateCode,value=c.StateName }).ToList();
 return ddllist;
```

Comment: It's a `Database First` project where tablename is a Model Class. I'm getting this error: `tablename does not contain a definition for select`. Where tablename is States that is as follows in Model folder: `public partial class States
    {
        public int StatesId { get; set; }
        public string StatesNAME { get; set; }
        public string StatesCode { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: Query is: `var ddlist = States.select(c => new { id = c.StateCode, value = c.StateName }).ToList();
            return ddllist;`